# With Semantic UI React, how to set the width and height for Image Avatar?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using: https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/image#image-example-avatar

```
      <Image avatar width={32} height={32} src={'/xxx.jpg'} />
```

Problem is, the Image avatar is not using the width and height params, and instead is using the assigned CSS:

```
.ui.avatar.image, .ui.avatar.image img, .ui.avatar.image svg, .ui.avatar.images .image, .ui.avatar.images img, .ui.avatar.images svg {
    margin-right: .25em;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    border-radius: 500rem;
}
```

How can I set the width and height for a `<Image avatar... >` using Semantic UI React?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Avatar image size is tied to the effective font size. A quick way to control the effective font size is

```
<Image style={{'font-size':42}} avatar src={'/xxx.jpg'}/>
```